# Set initial value of unknown type or overload operator for specific parameters type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm still learning C++ and fiddling with operator overload.

Now, I have to produce an output, while I don't know exactly what kind of data type it will be on input - it's specified in `makefile` and can be either `double`, `struct` or `enum`.

Code first:

```
#include <iostream>

#define TYPE Complex
//#define TYPE Symbol
//#define TYPE double

using namespace std;

struct Complex {
    double Re;
    double Im
};

enum Symbol {
    a, b, c, d, e
};

struct Vector {
    TYPE Data[4];
    //more in struct, but it's irrelevant
};

// operator * overloads for Complex and Symbol here
// output stream operator for Vector, Symbol and Complex
// are also overloaded

TYPE operator * (Vector A, Vector B) {
    TYPE Output;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        Output = A.Data[i] * B.Data[i];
    }

    return Output;
    // the output is garbage, because TYPE Output is not
    // set (to 0) at the beginning
}

int main {
    TYPE x;
    // ...
    x = SomeVectorA * SomeVectorB;
    cout << x << endl;
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

As the `TYPE Output` value is not set after initialisation, the overload will produce garbage at the output - it helps when I set it, but thtere is a problem. Setting initial values for each type is done in different way.

So for `Complex` it's

```
Complex X;
X.Re = 0;
X.Im = 0;
```

For `Symbol`

```
Symbol X;
X = e;
```

And for `double` as always.

The solution I came up with was to overload `operator` for specific type:

```
double operator * (Vector A, Vector B);   // [1]
Symbol operator * (Vector A, Vector B);   // [2]
Complex operator * (Vector A, Vector B);  // [3]
```

But the compiler throws me errors, because I already overloaded `[3]`, though for `Complex` type as an input, and after `[1]` I can't do `2.05 * 1.1` anymore due to incompatible data type.

I was also thinking about adding `Init()` function to `struct Complex` and `struct Vector`. But it won't work for `enum`.

Checking for `TYPE` doesn't work either, as compiler still throws errors.

**The question**
Is it any way to set various overload procedures for different input parameters or at least do something to avoid returning strange outputs in `TYPE operator * (Vector A, Vector B)`?

Comment: None of that is actually initialization. Any initialization would be done in the `Complex X;` or `Symbol X;` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try invoking default constructor, e.g:

```
TYPE Output = TYPE();
```

Comment: Thanks - it worked like a charm. It's so trivial that's it pretty shame that I've forgotten about it, especially if I always use it in C#...